# JavaScript - RegExp, test

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Почему метод **test** не всегда работает правильно - то он показывает **true** то **false**?
вот к примеру шаблон **/<(.|\n)*?>/g** на **tag** элементы, в дебагере смотрю возвращает true, но в if условие не заходит - говорит что типа он **false**, почему? 
Проверяю так:

```
var s = "<div></div>";
var pattern = /<(.|\n)*?>/g;
if(pattern.test(s))
  alert("found");
```

Comment: у меня патерн оюъявлен глобално, но я сделал проверку так (new RegExp(pattern)).test(s) - и всё нормально, но не могу понять почему если без RegExp то срабатывает через раз...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Флажок g - global, означает, регулярка будет запускаться несколько раз, причём проверка следующего раза будет проводится с места завершения предыдущего.

Итого получаем такой сценарий:

```
Проверяем строку в первый раз:
1) Сохраняем в регулярке строку
2) Находим и запоминаем точку соответствия
3) Отдаём True

Проверяем строку во второй раз:
1) Строка в регулярке соответствует переданной
2) Начинаем поиск с последней точки соответствия
3) Т.к. не находим - удаляем строку из регулярки
4) Отдаём False
```

Comment: всё, спасибо понял!!!